# Observation on Legendre's Conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, conjectures

Legendre's Conjecture states that there is a prime between every two perfect squares. It's almost certainly true, but remains unproven.

I conjecture that not only is that true, but for every $a\in\mathbb N$, there exists at least one $b\leq 2a$, so that $a^2<a^2+b<(a+1)^2$, such that $a^2+b$ *and* $a^2+b^2$ are prime. Empirically, this also appears almost certain.

I wanted to share that, but am also curious whether there's any special reason for it and will consider this post answered if anyone can find a counterexample, or give some reasoning on why this is (or is not) likely to be true.

Comment: I doubt it follows from it, it seems like a stronger statement. It may not relate at all and just be a probabilistic fluke, but I figured it was worth asking.

Comment: Obviously your conjecture implies Legendre's conjecture, because $a^2\lt a^2+b\lt(a+1)^2$ if $0<b<2a$. BTW did you test your conjecture? Up to how big $a$?

Comment: Through 5000 I think, and the candidate primes seemed to rise quickly. It's probably also true for $b<a$ for all $n>114$.

Comment: I note that the conjecture implies that you can always find a suitable $b$ such that $b(b-1)$ (an even number) is the difference of two primes. When $b=2$ is suitable, the existence of twin primes of the form $a^2+2$ and $a^2+4$ is implied.

Comment: @KeithBackman Good point. And this does happen a bit; for $a\leq 1000$, $b=2$ is a solution for $a=\{1, 3, 15, 33, 45, 57, 117, 147, 243, 255, 303, 375, 423, 447, 453, \
477, 573, 753, 837, 897, 903\}$, all but $1$ necessarily divisible by $3$.

Comment: Since a proof of this conjecture will be hopeless and you are already very convinced that it is true, are you interested in a larger search range for the $a$ satisfying the  conjecture, say $a\le 10^7$ ?

Comment: The conjecture is true for $1\le a\le 10^7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conjecture is almost certainly true (at least, for all sufficiently large $a$), and definitely out of reach of current technology, just like Legendre's conjecture. In fact, something much stronger is probably true (again, just like Legendre's conjecture): instead of taking $b\in [1,2a)$ you could take $b\in [1,C(\log a)^3]$, for some suitable constant $C>0$. (at least for all but finitely many $a$).

Here's a rough heuristic. The letter $c$ will denote some constant that might change between each occurrence, and depend on previous constants, but the precise value isn't really important.

Fix $a\in \mathbb{N}$. For each $b\in [0,2a)$ the heuristic 'chance' of $a^2+b$ being prime is, by the prime number theorem, $\approx 1/\log(a^2+b)\approx c/\log(a)$. The chance of $a^2+b^2$ being prime is $\approx 1/\log(a^2+b^2)\approx c/\log(a)$. Heuristically we assume these events are independent, so the chance of both being true for any $b\in[1,2a)$ is $\approx c/(\log a)^2$.

Again, for different $b$ these chances are heuristically independent, so we have the chance of all $b\in [1,X]\subset [1,2a)$ failing is

$$\approx (1-c/(\log a)^2)^{X} \approx e^{-cX/(\log a)^2}.$$

If we take $X=C(\log a)^3$ for some suitable constant $C>0$, then this chance is $\leq 1/a^2$, say, and in particular

$$\sum_{a\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(\textrm{no suitable }b\in[1,C(\log a)^3])$$

converges, and hence there are only finitely many $a$ which 'fail'.

(This heuristic is of course obviously flawed in that it doesn't take small congruence obstructions into account - e.g. if $a$ is even then all even $b$ automatically fail, but correcting for such obstructions will have a negligible effect on the overally behaviour.)